# Is it a convention to take the dipole moment vector $\vec p$ in the direction opposite to the electric field?

Tags: electromagnetism, charge, terminology, conventions, dipole-moment

Is it a convention to take the dipole moment vector $\vec p$ in the direction opposite to the electric field? Or it is proved by mathematics

Answer (score 3):

It is a convention that the dipole moment of a system of one positive charge and one negative charge points in the direction from the negative one to the positive one.

Instead of seeing this as being opposite to the direction of the field along the axis between them, see it as indicating the direction the field sprouting out of the “top” of the dipole, past the positive charge.

Comment: It's worth noting that the direction of the dipole moment vector is opposite i.e., from positive to negative charge in Chemistry. This is possibly to denote the direction in which the shared pair of electrons shift in a polar bond.